# Error: Transfering SPL Tokens via Python

Tags: spl-token, python, transfer

I have been transferring my SPL Tokens via python for 2 months and there is no problem.

With the same code, nothing has changed. When I did the transfer I got a signature and when I check this signature it says no data. It has been happening for the last to days.

Is it about the high usage of Solana chain?

```
try:

            client = Client(endpoint=SOLANA_RPC_URL_ENDPOINT)
            spl_client = Token(conn=client, pubkey=Pubkey.from_string(rows[i][1]),
                               program_id=Pubkey.from_string(rows[i][2]), payer=key_pair)

            try:
                source_token_account = \
                    spl_client.get_accounts_by_owner(owner=source, commitment=None, encoding='base64').value[
                        0].pubkey

            except:
                source_token_account = spl_client.create_associated_token_account(owner=source,
                                                                                  skip_confirmation=False,
                                                                                  recent_blockhash=None)
            try:
                dest_token_account = \
                    spl_client.get_accounts_by_owner(owner=dest, commitment=None, encoding='base64').value[0].pubkey
            except:
                dest_token_account = spl_client.create_associated_token_account(owner=dest, skip_confirmation=False,
                                                                                recent_blockhash=None)


            transaction = spl_client.transfer(source=source_token_account, dest=dest_token_account,
                                              owner=key_pair, amount=int(rows[i][4]),
                                              multi_signers=None, opts=None, recent_blockhash=None)
```

Thanks,
Best regards

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're doing in your code. Given the limited information in your question, it's difficult to provide useful help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. I am using Helius Rpc and trying to transfer spl coins to another wallet. I can get the transaction ID but when I check this ID on Solscan it says no data everytime. So I can not transfer coins. I am using the same Helius RPC for buying a coin but there is not any problem with that. I don't know what is the difference.